# Cannot invoke observeForever on a background thread

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, androidx

I've been using an `observeForever()` method as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44991770/3499145) to test Room and LiveData for a while, and it has worked flawlessly. But when I changed to Android Studio 3.2 (or if it was the `androidx` refactoring, not sure), that method suddenly stopped working, throwing a

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot invoke observeForever on a background thread
```

How can we fix this?

Comment: assert main thread checking has been added in new androidx library livedata class. I think it's no longer can be used in background thread.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I solved it by adding the rule `InstantTaskExecutorRule`. According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/core/executor/testing/InstantTaskExecutorRule) it will

> A JUnit Test Rule that swaps the background executor used by the Architecture Components with a different one which executes each task synchronously.

So one needs to add

```
@get:Rule
val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
```

to the test class for it to work. The Java equivalent would be

```
@Rule
public InstantTaskExecutorRule instantTaskExecutorRule = new InstantTaskExecutorRule();
```

You will also need to add

```
androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.0.0"
```

to your models `build.gradle` dependencies.

Comment: where to put it?

Comment: As stated in the text - "to the test class".

@Runwith(Junit4::class.java)
class YourTest {
@Rule......
}

Comment: @Nurseyit put it as an annotation before the test function name. For example, `@get:Rule var... @Test fun test_InsertData()...`

Answer (score 6):

As a beginner to this approach, accepted answer was a little bit vague for me. So just trying to explain it

add this in your `build.gradle`

```
androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.0.0
```

Now we need to add `rule` on test function. Lets say that I have a test function `writeAndReadCategory` then it will look like this in `kotlin`

```
    @get:Rule
    val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
    @Test
    fun writeAndReadCategory() {
        ....
    }
```