# What does a Live Data type method return in java?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Im writing a test case for my Room Database class and i have all my queries with return type LiveData. like this.

```
@Query("Select * from location")
LiveData<List<LocationDetails>> getAllRecords();
```

As far as i understand, wherever i wanted to use these queries in my code. i used them with .observables so i can change my views accordingly. and those observables calls, return the List for me to play with. so i think it gives me the value of LiveData. The same as, what

```
LiveData<List<LocationDetails>>.getvalue()
```

does. (i know its not like that but just to give you an idea of what i meant.)

So while writing my unit tests for this. I have to use the queries but obviously without the observables. and if i do it like this :

```
LiveData<List<LocationDetails>> parsingObject =  mDao.getAllRecords();
```

It gives me this error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at genesis.com.getlocation.MyDaoTest.validateGetRecord(MyDaoTest.java:70).
```

but no error on assertNotNull(parsingObject).

But if i make a query without the LiveData type (like below). and use that in my tests. Then i ofcourse get a list to work with and it runs fine.

```
List<LocationDetails>;
```

So, can someone tell me how do i make that work with LiveData type method ?

Test.class

```
package genesis.com.getlocation;
import android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Room;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import java.util.List;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MyDaoTest {

    private LocationDetails locationDetails = new LocationDetails();
    private Database mDb;
    private MyDao mDao;

    @Before
    public void createDb() {

        Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
        mDb = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context, Database.class).build();
        mDao = mDb.myDao();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        mDb.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void validateInsertRecord(){
        JSONObject jsonStringOject= new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonStringOject.put("name", "asd");
            jsonStringOject.put("address", "asd");
            jsonStringOject.put("date", "asd");
            jsonStringOject.put("note", "asd");
            jsonStringOject.put("radioButtonValue", "asd");

            locationDetails.setObject(jsonStringOject.toString());
            locationDetails.setLongitude(654654);
            locationDetails.setLatitude(564654);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail();
        }
        mDao.insertRecord(locationDetails);
    }

    @Test
    public void validateGetRecord(){
        LiveData<List<LocationDetails>> parsingObject =  mDao.getAllRecords();
        assertNotNull(parsingObject);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        for (LocationDetails location : parsingObject.getValue()) {
            String ObjectString = location.getObject();
            JSONObject json;
            try {
                json = new JSONObject(ObjectString);
                bundle.putString("name",json.getString("name"));
                bundle.putString("address",json.getString("address"));
                bundle.putString("date",json.getString("date"));
                bundle.putString("note",json.getString("note"));
                bundle.putString("radioButtonValue",json.getString("radioButtonValue"));
                bundle.putString("id", String.valueOf(location.getId()));
                bundle.putString("latitude", String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
                bundle.putDouble("longitude", location.getLongitude());
                System.out.println(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
                assertEquals(String.valueOf(locationDetails.getLatitude()),bundle.getString("latitude"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you share your test class code?

Comment: @JeelVankhede. Ive edited the code with the test class in it.

Comment: Have you checked about your **`mDao`** object? assert if it is null or not. Let me know if it's `null` (I guess it's null) @Muhammad

Comment: @JeelVankhede. It isnt , i checked. Like i said .if i use a List , it works fine

Comment: Please look into this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44271247/10271334

Comment: @JeelVankhede. Yes thankyou so much . that helps me.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Can you put this as an answer , so i can upvote you?